# MySql - Sorting events

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to sort the records from the earliest events in the future to the top and records from the past to the end.

For example:

Today is 18.12.2015.

I have these records in the table:

```
+-----+------------+--------------+
| id  | title      | date         |
+-----+------------+--------------+
| 1   | Title 1    | 2015-12-12   |
| 2   | Title 2    | 2015-12-15   |
| 3   | Title 3    | 2015-12-20   |
| 4   | Title 4    | 2015-12-21   |
| 5   | Title 5    | 2015-12-22   |
| 6   | Title 6    | 2015-12-23   |
+-----+------------+--------------+
```

I need to output ordered as follows:

```
 1. Title 3
 2. Title 4
 3. Title 5
 4. Title 6
 5. Title 2
 6. Title 1
```

Can I do it with the standart query `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried?

Comment: You can `UNION` two selects - one for "earlier" events and one for "past".

Comment: Ok, UNION, thank you. And in one query it does not?

Comment: I really don't understand why this question got so many downvotes. It may not be something special, but it's definitely not as trivial as it seems at first glance.

Comment: I didn't think it's trivial. However, it seems to lack a bit of effort. Of course there's a solution using orderby, but as it stands, it's not obvious if an attempt was made or if we're just asked to do some homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `date` > NOW() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), `date`))
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be609/8)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done in a single SQL statement, however you could try something like this:

```
USE blue;
CREATE TABLE test_temp ( id INT NOT NULL, title VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, s_date DATE NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO test_temp (id, title, s_date) SELECT id, title, s_date FROM test_table ORDER BY s_date ASC;
SELECT * FROM test_temp WHERE s_date > DATE(NOW())
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM test_temp WHERE s_date <= DATE(NOW()); 
DROP TABLE test_temp;
```

Result :

3, Title 3, 2015-12-20

4, Title 4, 2015-12-21

5, Title 5, 2015-12-22

6, Title 6, 2015-12-23

1, Title 1, 2015-12-12

2, Title 2, 2015-12-15

Hope the above example helps.

Regards,

Steve

Comment: Giorgos' solution is a lot more efficient.